# Is there any way to create 3D environment with navtive mobile development like Zepeto?

Tags: android, kotlin, 3d

I am looking for a way to insert a mini game feature in my app.

And I found this.

https://developer.android.com/games/guides

But It says about implementing games with the engines like defold, godot, unity, unreal.
I am an Android Developer who uses Kotlin. Someone needs to make a game and export it and import it to Android Studio project. So, I can't make the games and maintain the source code. So, This document isn't helpful.

And I found [rive app](https://rive.app/). It's like lottie but can add some events and listeners with number or boolean conditions. It has State Machine that can connect the native app and interact between the rive animation and the native app. That's it. And It doesn't support everything like normal game engines do. I need to make timelines to create animations and no sound, etc.

I tried to find better way to implement an app like miniapp. And I've found Zepeto. it uses a lot of 3D animations. It uses Jetpack compose. That's very interesting point. How can I implement 3D modelings with native app? Is there any way to create 3D animation and the virtual environment like Zepeto?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your issue was with the game engines you mentioned. It sounds like maybe what you mean is you would need to rely on someone else that knows how to use those game engines and associated programming languages, and you're not able to invest time in learning them? Are you just asking for a game engine that can be programmed in Kotlin?

Comment: You can always work with OpenGL directly without a game engine. The Android SDK includes a bridge for that, which is what some of those engines you listed use incidentally. You can also use a Kotlin-compatible game framework like libGDX or Korge to do the heavy lifting.